# Umbraco 5.1 display image in template

Tags: umbraco5

Could someone give me a step-by-step description on how to display an image within an Umbraco 5.1 template.

It must be so ridiculously simple that no one has bothered to describe it.  If you could make it step-by-step that would be great.  I've now read and attempted to implement all sorts of xslt and razor statements, partials and marcos and haven't even got close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common point of confusion in Umbraco is that there actually two different field types, one for 'uploader', and one for 'media picker'.

With uploader, you upload the image directly to the content page.

With media, you upload the image to the Media Library, and then reference the content across the site, using the media picker control.

Since you say your content has a media id, I'm assuming that you're attempting to use a media picker--Here's the easiest way that you can output the image chosen by your media picker field.

```
@Umbraco.GetMediaUrl(@CurrentPage.MyImageFieldAlias)
```

Answer (score 2):

I do like this in umbraco5

```
<img src="@umbraco.GetMediaUrl(Model,"propertyAlias")" alt="image"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
src="@Umbraco.GetMediaUrl(Model.Id, "image")"
```

where `Model.Id` is the imageid of a perticular image.

Comment: Thanks Usama but could you give a bit more of a hint.  I have spent the last hour trying every combination I could think of without success.  The image is in the Media section and has an id of content://p__nhibernate/v__guid/a6cccd27a3ce4d0bb2bea06500feccb7

Answer (score 0):

I do it  like this .

First create a Umabraco macro. Give it a relevant name (TopLeftImage)
Now use it in the page like this :-

```
<img src= <umbraco:Item field="TopLeftImage" useIfEmpty="TopLeftImage"  runat="server"/>   />
```

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps,you will definitely get rid from this problem:

1.first create a image `field` in umbraco Cms using `media picker` data type,then upload a image 
to that field.

2.Create a `asp:image` control in `visual studio` page

```
<asp:image ID="imgLogo" runat="server">
```

3.Then `Code Behind` do the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory;
using Umbraco.Core;
using umbraco;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media;
using umbraco.interfaces;

    public partial class UserControls_Header_Nav : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        umbraco.NodeFactory.Node headerNode = uQuery.GetNode(1139);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
            {
            LoadData();
            }
        }


    private void LoadData()
    {

        if (headerNode != null)
        {

            if (headerNode.GetProperty("imgLogo") != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerNode.GetProperty("imgLogo").Value))
            {
                string url;
                Int32 PhotoId = Convert.ToInt32(headerNode.GetProperty("imgLogo").Value);
                var media = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.Media(PhotoId);
                var file = media.getProperty("umbracoFile");
                url = (string)file.Value;
                imgLogo.ImageUrl = url;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and this will work for you :-)